# Get rid of unnecessary components laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4, frameworks

Hi I just made one batch system and api.
One is for storing data to database with crontab, 
And the other is for retrievone the data and creating json file with crontab and when it gets access a specific url, the corresponding json file returns to users.

So now Id love to get rid of unused components.  So what are the nessesary components to make them work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to get rid of anything.

Laravel uses Lazy Loading - which means they are only loada/used when they are actually needed. So there is no real performance changes by removing items.

Plus most of the default components are required anyway.

Edit: there is now [Laravel Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) - which is *exactly* what you are looking for.